# Traffic from Google News

Tags: google-analytics, google-news

I would like to create dashboard for all traffic from Google News. First filter is for referral this is simply (source) -> news.google.com but How I create second filter for organic traffic with special url https://www.google.com/?tbm=nws ?How I get organic traffic from google news to dashboard?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link from  Moz explaining how to do this for Shopping, though it should work the same way for news:
https://moz.com/ugc/tracking-google-shopping-traffic-with-google-analytics-14244

The difference will be Field B -> Extract B, which you'll want to set as:
(\?|&)tbm=nws

Then change the Output to -> Constructor: Campaign Source to "google news" instead of "google shopping" (or use whatever words you want in the reports).

Comment: Your solution is not working. I checked real time, when I click to article in news section in search reasult and I haven´t got visit with source google news. The same is in news tab in google,